# Is this called a density graph or a distribution graph

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology, education, density-function

What would you call the following graph? is it a density plot or distribution plot or both?

Can view image if you click image link

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGmfm.png)

Comment: The vertical axis label might be an important clue.

Comment: I'd call it a histogram.